# Alexa won't recognize valid json feed

Tags: python, json, aws-lambda, rss, alexa-skills-kit

> Error: There was an error parsing the feed. Please ensure that the
>   feed is valid JSON or RSS.

For the flash briefing skill I can't get Alexa to recognize my Lambda function return as valid JSON. When I call API gateway on this Lambda function it returns valid JSON.
Why won't Alexa recognize it?  I've read over the [feed guildlines here](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/flashbriefing/flash-briefing-skill-api-feed-reference.html) and have come up short.

```
import json
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    js = [ 
          {
          "uid": "EXAMPLE_CHANNEL_MULTI_ITEM_JSON_TTS_1",
          "updateDate": "2016-04-10T00:00:00.0Z",
          "titleText": "Multi Item JSON (TTS)",
          "mainText": "This channel has multiple TTS JSON items. This is the first item.",
          "redirectionUrl": "https://www.amazon.com"
         },
         {
          "uid": "EXAMPLE_CHANNEL_MULTI_ITEM_JSON_TTS_2",
          "updateDate": "2016-04-10T00:00:00.0Z",
          "titleText": "Multi Item JSON (TTS)",
          "mainText": "This channel has multiple TTS JSON items. This is the second item.",
          "redirectionUrl": "https://www.amazon.com"
         }
        ]

    js = json.dumps(js)
    return js
```

returned string

```
"[{\"mainText\": \"This channel has multiple TTS JSON items. This is   the first item.\", \"redirectionUrl\": \"https://www.amazon.com\", \"uid\": \"EXAMPLE_CHANNEL_MULTI_ITEM_JSON_TTS_1\", \"titleText\": \"Multi Item JSON (TTS)\", \"updateDate\": \"2016-04-10T00:00:00.0Z\"}, {\"mainText\": \"This channel has multiple TTS JSON items. This is the second item.\", \"redirectionUrl\": \"https://www.amazon.com\", \"uid\": \"EXAMPLE_CHANNEL_MULTI_ITEM_JSON_TTS_2\", \"titleText\": \"Multi Item JSON (TTS)\", \"updateDate\": \"2016-04-10T00:00:00.0Z\"}]"
```

I have "validated" this output as valid JSON using [this online tool](https://jsonlint.com/).

If anyone has a properly formatted JSON feed that has been accepted by Amazon please paste that code below.

Comment: Not sure if this happened while pasting code, but currently that is not valid JSON because the `mainText` value is on multiple lines.

Comment: Just guessing: incorrect MIME type or charset?

Comment: Did you make sure to encode it to UTF-8? Amazon states that is a requirement. So you need `js = json.dumps(js).encode('utf-8')`

Comment: I added encoding that may have helped but has not solved the problem completely.  @Robᵩ  how would I go about changing the MIME.  Right now I'm simply returning the JSON through an AWS API gateway.  Do I need to add some other headers to say what datatype it is?  If so how would I do that.  Amazon has this cute little file type on their website.  I cant tell if it's decorative or part of the code being returned.  I've tried to add it to the string with no success.    
    Copied (Content-Type: application/json
    ...
[
      {
        "uid": "EXAMPLE_CHANNEL_MULTI_ITEM_JSON_TTS_1",...)